# "in case of" + "respectively"

Tags: grammar, commas, articles

I would like to write something like:

> In cases of the A and B models, the run-time analysis of the algorithm
>   is shown in Figures X and Y, respectively.

I mean:

```
A model -> Fig X
B model -> Fig Y
```

Is it correct?
I would like to say it in one sentence if possible.

Comment: Welcome to the site!, Yes, *respectively* is used correctly. The only thing that sounds off is "in cases of the". How about simply *For models A and B, ...*?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! No need to say "thanks" within your question, though you can of course leave comments as well as fill out your own user profile :) We like to get right to the heart of the matter in questions and answers - it makes the site more useful and easy to read for anyone who has a similar question in the future!

Answer (score 1):

Your example is correct but reordering it slightly may be more clear:

> The run-time analysis of the algorithm is shown in Figures X and Y for the cases of the A and B models, respectively.

Slightly guessing at the meaning of your specific terms, I would reorder the entire sentence as such:

> Run-time analysis using the A and B models are shown in Figures X and Y, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context in which the sentence appears.

If you mentioned A and B models in the previous sentence you could simply say *'In both cases, ...'"*

If there is more than the A and B models then you'll need to rearrange your sentence.

Also, you're referring to the A and B models which are algorithms but you also use the explicit "algorithm" in the same sentence.

*'Runtime analysis of A and B algorithms are shown in figures X and Y, respectively.'*

Comment: No, unfortunately models are not algorithms. Many model, one algorithm. So I still go with "For models A and B,..." solution.